# Any heuristic explanation on why sieve methods can not prove Goldbach conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

Any heuristic explanation on why sieve methods can not prove strong Goldbach conjecture ?

I remember that Terence Tao published a blog and gave an heuristic explanation on why
circle methods very likely will NOT be able to prove strong Goldbach conjecture (http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/heuristic-limitations-of-the-circle-method/#more-5963)

Is there any similar heuristic explanation on why sieve methods can NOT prove strong Goldbach conjecture ?

A related question, Is there any similar heuristic explanation on why Schnirelmann density methods can NOT prove strong Goldbach conjecture ?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993648/any-results-for-small-number-goldbach-conjecture-research, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006094/what-is-the-relationship-between-grh-and-goldbach-conjecture, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009269/any-results-to-generalize-weighted-sieve-to-three-parameters for similar users (but different accounts).